# does google app engine support twitter api,fbconnect,facebook api,linkedin api

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to make an application on cloud wherei m trying to update facebook-linnkedin-twitter in a single update.so ,does google app engine support twitter api,fbconnect,facebook api,linkedin api.

Comment: Have you tried using their APIs on AppEngine?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You can call these APIs using [urlfetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) and parse the response using [simplejson](http://code.google.com/p/simplejson/) if the response is JSON or [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) if the response is XML.